# Error(10,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma final

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, extract-error-message

```
create or replace TRIGGER "VALIDATE_DOA_DOD" BEFORE UPDATE ON IN_PATIENT 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DOD < :OLD.DOA THEN


    enter code here


 RAISE EX_INVALID_DOD;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTIION
    WHEN EX_INVALID_DOD THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Date Of Discharge must be greater or equal to Date of Admition');

END;
```

Comment: Just add another `End` in the final

Comment: THANKS NOW FACING THIS ERROR (Error(8,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; )

Comment: That's another question ! , you need to complete the code

Comment: The code is complete plzz help

Comment: You need to add one of the following: := . ( @ % ; ) after WHEN

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. replace the `'enter code here'` with something meaningful, or remove it
2. edit `EXCEPTIION` into `EXCEPTION`
3. declare your exception `EX_INVALID_DOD`

So:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "VALIDATE_DOA_DOD" BEFORE UPDATE ON IN_PATIENT 
FOR EACH ROW
declare
    EX_INVALID_DOD exception;
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DOD < :OLD.DOA THEN


     --enter code here


     RAISE EX_INVALID_DOD;
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN EX_INVALID_DOD THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Date Of Discharge must be greater or equal to Date of Admition');

END;
```